# Map object, remove elements in a single loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is a concise and the efficient way to remove elements of a Map object in a single loop upon some condition?

Iterating on the map's entries() can do it but calling entries() at each iteration doesn't look efficient

```
let name_value_map = new Map([['One', 1], ['Two', 2], ['Three', 3], ['Four', 4]])

for (let pair of name_value_map.entries())
     if (pair[1] <= 3)
         name_value_map.delete(pair[0])
```

Other ideas?

Comment: why not filter before creating Map something like this: let name_value_map = new Map([['One', 1], ['Two', 2], ['Three', 3], ['Four', 4]].filter(pair => pair[1] > 3))

Comment: I think the only way to do this is iterate through the whole map. It can't be more efficient than this.

Comment: Since your code works and you're looking for a specific improvement, this question is a good candidate for *[codereview.se]* (notwithstanding the answers below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Map.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) method:

```js
const name_value_map = new Map([['One', 1], ['Two', 2], ['Three', 3], ['Four', 4]]);

name_value_map.forEach((v, k, m) => v <= 3 && m.delete(k));

console.log([...name_value_map.entries()]); // SO console doesn't display Map
```

Comment: It works but I discarded that approach thinking that deleting the first element would skip the second one in the next iteration (as it happens with an array, : 

`arr.forEach((i, ix) => i[1] <= 3 && arr.splice(ix,1));`)

Answer (score 3):

Use `entries` and `filter` along with spread operator `...`

```
name_value_map = new Map([...name_value_map.entries()].filter( s => s[1] > 3 ));
```

**Demo**

```js
var name_value_map = new Map([
  ['One', 1],
  ['Two', 2],
  ['Three', 3],
  ['Four', 4]
]);

name_value_map = new Map([...name_value_map.entries()].filter(s => s[1] > 3));

console.log(name_value_map); //check the browser's console
```

Comment: You are applying the solution to the array used to initialize the map but that was only for the example, suppose that the map comes already filled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.from`, then use `.filter`, and convert back to `Map`. **This won't mutate** the orginal `Map`.

> The Array.from() method creates a new Array instance from an
>   array-like or iterable object.

```js
let name_value_map = new Map([['One', 1], ['Two', 2], ['Three', 3], ['Four', 4]])

const filtered = new Map(
 Array.from(name_value_map).filter(([,value]) => value > 3)
);
  
console.log([...filtered.entries()])
```

Comment: TIL `([,value]) =>`, never thought about doing that. I guess that saves allocating an unused variable?

Comment: @msanford I suppose, but I use it to keep the code clean.

Answer (score -1):

Why not to use an object ?

```
const ob = {
    One: 1,
    Two: 2,
    Three: 3,
    Four: 4
};

for (const key of Object.keys(ob)) {
    if (ob[key] <= 3)
        delete ob[key];
}
```

Comment: Because OP is working on a `Map`, presumably for a reason. Maps provide some advantages that Objects don't. And since this is a small performance question, recasting the whole Map as an Object is probably incredibly costly. (I didn't DV you but I'm sure that's why.)