# Map.forEach, why deleting items in the loop works?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

If you delete items of an array in a forEach loop you can miss some elements, like in:

```js
    let arr = [['One', 1], ['Two', 2], ['Three', 3], ['Four', 4]]
    arr.forEach((i, ix) => i[1] <= 3 && arr.splice(ix,1));          // Two is not deleted
    console.log(arr)
```

But if you apply forEach to a Map object it works:

```js
let map = new Map( [['One', 1], ['Two', 2], ['Three', 3], ['Four', 4]] );
map.forEach( (value,key)  => value <= 3 && map.delete(key));
console.log([...map.entries()])
```

What are the internals in Map.forEach that assure trustable deletes and other operations (inserts?)

(This originated in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001622/map-object-remove-elements-in-a-single-loop?noredirect=1#comment87019851_50001622))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you delete items of an array in a forEach loop you can miss some elements

See [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> If the values of existing elements of the array are changed, the value passed to callback will be the value at the time forEach() visits them; elements that are deleted before being visited are not visited. **If elements that are already visited are removed (e.g. using shift()) during the iteration, later elements will be skipped** [...]

---

> What are the internals in Map.forEach that assure trustable deletes and other operations (inserts?)

See [`Map.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach):

> The forEach method executes the provided callback once for **each key of the map** which actually exist.

And as the key is not bound to the order, it won't affect the loop. Yes it is executed in insertion order, but that does not shift the loop when using `forEach` to remove elements from the map.

Answer (score 2):

The array has dynamic indices and if one element gets spliced, the rest of the elements just move and gets new inidces.

That is the reason, because you splice the wrong parts by iterating from the beginning.

---

By using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), the indices are used as keys and if one item gets deleted, all other items of the map keeps their key.

By later rendering an array, the missing items and their keys are gone.